# How to store and retrieve python objects in mongodb based on a key

Tags: python, mongodb

Currently I am dumping large python object values to a local file using

```
joblib.dump(gmix,filename.pkl)
```

I would like to store this in a mongodb identified by fileid.

Also I would like to retrieve this .pkl based on file_id from mongodb.

Using gridfs, I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: can only write strings or file-like objects

The way to use gridfs is as follows:

```
file_handler.put(gmix,filename=gmmfile)
```

I am new to mongodb and python, any leads or solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, I guess you should do that then. This isn't really a question and far too broad to be addressed here. MongoDB - https://www.mongodb.com Pymongo - https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/

Comment: Well, my point was just to get the command to store a file so that it can be retrieved with a file id, using GRIDFS, I could not figure out an approach to store  <key,Fileobject> pair